# Find all the group homomorphisms from $G_1$ into $G_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, circles

Find all the group homomorphisms from $G_1$ into $G_2$ wher $G_1=\{e, a, a^2|a^3=e\}$ and $G_2=\{e,b,b^2, b^3|b^4=e\}$.

So I know that $G_1=\langle a\rangle$ and $G_2=\langle b \rangle$, also $o(a)=3$ and $o(b)=4$ so $(3,4)=1$ that means there exists only one homomorphism. Which one?

Comment: It's always worth checking the trivial cases.

Comment: There is one homeomorphism that exists between _any_ two groups, and if you don't know which one it is yet, I suggest that once you do find it, you memorize it. It's an important group homomorphism.

Comment: @Arthur how should I do it?

Comment: @Atstovas What is the image of $e$ under an arbitrary homomorphism

Comment: @YourongZang i have no idea

Comment: Well, then we start there. What _is_ a homomorphism? Do you know that?

Comment: @Atstovas by following Arthur's hints, you will be able to get the answer easily.

Comment: @Arthur a homomorphism is a map between two structures with same type

Comment: @Atstovas You gotta be more specific when dealing with special algebraic structures.

Comment: @Atstovas https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Group_homomorphism

Comment: Yes, that's what a homomorphsim is, in the abstract sense. However, we know we are dealing with groups, so you can be more specific about what a homomorphism is in this context. What is a group homomorphsim? What requirements do we place on it?

Comment: H(a*b)=h(a)*h(b)

Comment: Cool. And this means that what happens to the identity element?

Comment: @Arthur so it is h(e) to e

Comment: Yes, that's right. And with your two groups, in your particular example, what can be done with $a$? What options are allowed for $h(a)$?

Comment: Now I dont know. Maybe h(a) =e